# Python array weirdness when doing simple lowpass filter - output is 0

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am hoping someone can help. This is very odd. The exact same code is working with other inputs (e.g. Dirac Delta, step function, [1,-1,1,-1,...]). The output plot works as expected with the other inputs.  I am really at a loss.

The raw lowpass calculation shown below (e.g. *a0 * x[n] + a1 * xn1*) works (i.e. results in [0, .5, .5, -.5, -.5, ...]), but when assigning it to y[n], it fails (0 is assigned each time through the loop).

Any idea what I am missing?

```py
# create simple signal array [0, 1, 0, -1, ...]
x = []
for n in range(0,125):
    x.append(0)
    x.append(1)
    x.append(0)
    x.append(-1)

y = np.full_like(x,7)
a0 = 0.5
a1 = 0.5
xn1 = 0.0

# simple lowpass filter
for n in range(np.size(x)):
    y[n] = a0 * x[n] + a1 * xn1  # why is this always 0?
    xn1 = x[n]

# simple plotting function (output shown in image below)
# should output 0 then [.5, .5, -.5, -.5, ...]
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
fig.suptitle(title)

ax1.stem(x[0:10])
ax1.set_title('halfNyq (x)')
ax1.locator_params(axis="x", nbins=16)
ax1.locator_params(axis="y", nbins=7)

ax2.stem(y[0:10])
ax2.set_title('output (y)')
ax2.locator_params(axis="x", nbins=16)
ax2.locator_params(axis="y", nbins=7)
fig.tight_layout(pad=1.0)
```

[image: Output of wpf.printSignalFunctionOutput]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `print(y.dtype)` somewhere to check the data type of `y`, you may see it's `int64`. The source list `x` has only `int` objects, so `full_like` thinks you want an integer array.

The [documentation for numpy says](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#array-creation):

> For example, you can create an array from a regular Python list or tuple using the array function. The type of the resulting array is deduced from the type of the elements in the sequences.

Change the values in `x` to e.g. `0.0` etc. so that they're `float`s and not `int`s. Or pass the `dtype` argument to `full_like()` to force the type, e.g. `y = np.full_like(x, 7, dtype=float)`.

Comment: Didn't think of that (just getting started with python - for real, anyway).  Thank you very much!

Comment: @mewa6, darn, took a while to find where the docs actually say it works like that... But yep, numpy is a bit special here, since the arrays actually have a fixed data type, unlike what would happen if `y` was a regular `list` (like you get with Anton's `.tolist()`)

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly assign elements to numpy array in your loop. You can change it to list:

```
y = np.full_like(x,7).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you bother to trace your computations?  That explains quite well why this is always 0.

```
for n in range(np.size(x)):
    y[n] = a0 * x[n] + a1 * xn1  # why is this always 0?
    print(y[n], x[n], xn1)
    xn1 = x[n]
```

Output:

```
0 0 0.0
0 1 0
0 0 1
0 -1 0
0 0 -1
0 1 0
0 0 1
0 -1 0
0 0 -1
...
```

At every iteration, you set `xn1` to the value that neatly complements the next value of `x[n]`, thereby ensuring that each `y` value is zero.  This isn't a band-pass filter, it's a noise-cancelling circuit for cyclic wave forms.

Comment: Are you sure? Try `a = a0 * x[n] + a1 * xn1; print(a, x[n], xn1)`. 0.5 * 0 + 0.5 * 1 = 0.5, just like they expected to get.

Comment: Hi Prune.  Yes, as @ilkkachu shows, this does not do what you are saying.  The output is as I described in the initial question.  I do appreciate your offering another thing to look for though!